# Backdrop-filter blur on two overlapping, partially opaque elements

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to have 2 overlapping, partially opaque circles, which smoothly apply `backdrop-filter: blur` to the elements behind them. Consider the following code:

[Code Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-star-ci26oc)

```css
.background {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553356084-58ef4a67b2a7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1287&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
}

.left {
  left: 0px;
}

.right {
  right: 0px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container1 {
  top: 100px;
}

.box1 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}

.container2 {
  top: 230px;
  /* opacity: 0.3; */
  filter: opacity(0.3);
}

.box2 {
  background: black;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}
```

```html
<div className="background">
  <div className="container container1">
    <div className="box box1 left" />
    <div className="box box1 right" />
  </div>
  <div className="container container2">
    <div className="box box2 left" />
    <div className="box box2 right" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This produces the following:

[image]

As you can see, the top 2 circles correctly blur their background, but since each individually has its own opacity, there's an unwanted discoloration/outline where they overlap.

The bottom 2 circles are correctly colored, but the `backdrop-filter: blur` doesn't take effect. It appears not to work correctly with the parent's `opacity`. A partial workaround can be found by changing `.container2` to have:

```css
filter: opacity(0.3);
backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
```

This produces the following:

[image]

This is much closer, but produces an unwanted blur at the edges of the containing block. Is there any way to cleanly blur just the two circles?

[Code Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-star-ci26oc)

It's also worth noting that for my application, these two circle elements will be animated and moved around relative to one another, so solutions involving images will not work. Solutions involving canvas or svg are totally acceptable. Unfortunately, it seems that svg visual elements (like paths) do not support `backdrop-filter`.

Comment: The code you provided in the question doesn't render what's in the image. This seems like primarily a CSS question, so maybe strip out the React stuff and just get the snippet working. Once you have a fix you can backport it into your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using `clip-path`. I think you can easily move the circles by manipulating their attributes. Hope this helps.

```css
body{
 background: url("https://placekitten.com/350/200")
}
.masked{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  clip-path: url(#mask);
  backdrop-filter:blur(20px)
}
```

```html
<div class="masked">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 100">
    <clipPath id="mask">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
      <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="50" />
    </clipPath>
  </svg>
</div>
```